# single thread process on multi cpu and threads

Tags: process, operating-system, cpu

lets says I have single threaded process and 2 CPU each with 2 cores.
How many processes can I run at any moment? 2 or 4? I couldn't find a clear answer for this.
is the cpu bound to he process and a core is wasted so only 2 processes can run at the same time or there is optimizations and we can run 4 processes at the same time on the 4 cores even if we only have 2 cpus?

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit. The number of cores or CPUs has no connection whatsoever to the number of processes you can run.

I'm typing this answer to you on a machine with 8 cores that's currently executing 218 processes with a total of 524 threads.

> is the cpu bound to he process and a core is wasted so only 2 processes can run at the same time or there is optimizations and we can run 4 processes at the same time on the 4 cores even if we only have 2 cpus?

A CPU has no idea what a process is and doesn't care whether a thread it's executing is associated with a process or not. Processes are OS concepts and CPUs don't know or care about them.

Comment: I guess it depends on you definition of 'run'. Your box can have 8 threads in the running state at any moment.   I wonder what the OP meant?  I'm gonna vote to close as 'unclear'.